# Change GLTF material in Aframe

Tags: three.js, aframe, gltf

I'm trying to make some flame in Aframe using a mesh I get on Sketchfab. My problem is the flame mesh have shadow and is dark. How can i change this ? I try setting material `emissive` and `emissiveIntensity` but it doesn't affect the result...

Here is the code rendered by Chrome and a screenshot

```
<a-entity gltf-model="#fire1"
 position="1 1 1"
 scale="0.2 0.2 0.2"
 rotation="0 15 0"
 spinning=""
 emissive-light=""
 material=""
 visible="">

   <a-light position=""
    intensity="1"
    light=""
    angle="-180"
    distance="20"
    type="spot"
    rotation=""
    scale=""
    visible=""></a-light>
</a-entity>
```

[image: A not so flamish flame]

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that the GLTF loader ignores any other components that try to modify its material properties at the A-Frame layer. You will have to dive into the THREEjs layer underneath. Don McCurdy gives a great example of that [here](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/blob/99535cd878eb36cb25cdcda4a32a40eb248c990a/src/misc/cube-env-map.js). Notice that his component listens for the 'object3dset' event then modifies the THREEjs nodes directly.

Of course, if you are just trying to lighten the scene you could add an [ambient light](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/docs/components/light.md) :)

Comment: Good answer; one clarification is that the `material` component _only_ works on 3D models in the special case of an OBJ file without any MTL materials. With any other format/file, you have to modify using the three.js layer as described here.